# How to get the animate affect of keyboard of iPhone in UIbuttons in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

Hai am trying to animation effect of iOS keyboard into the buttons of my application. In the image on pressing O it became Bigger and displayed the alphabet chosen, i am trying to get the same effect into one of UIbuttons in swift. On clicking the button there should also appear just like picture a bigger frame and display the text it.

[image: Picture of the Keyboard and animation that i want]

Thanks

Comment: nothing i don't know where to start i just have a button

Answer (score 0):

Increase the size of UIButton with

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: DURATION, animations: {
     btn.frame.width += 20
     btn.frame.height += 20
}, completion: { (success) in

})
```

or you can also try this answer
[Scale UIButton Animation- Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31320819/scale-uibutton-animation-swift)