# Create video of 'zooming in on an image'

Tags: ios, swift, video, uiimage, avassetwriter

I have a `UIImage` and I want to create a video of 'zooming in onto the image'.

I've tried creating an array, `var imageArray:[UIImage] = []`, and then populating it with images, then using `AVAssetWriter` to convert the images to a video, but it doesn't look very good and takes a long time to create enough images to make the video smooth.

It's easy to animate an image enlarging / 'zooming in', but for my purposes I need to have a video to export.

What's the best way to approach this? It seems like it should be simple to create a video of a static image zooming in? Just like an iMovie transition, or a screen saver, except a video.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try scaling image up with animation?

Here's the link to that : [Scale UIButton Animation- Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31320819/scale-uibutton-animation-swift)